# Query database using result from previous query and combining them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using dynamic sql, to query the database:

```
    DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(5000);
    SET @VALUE = '123'
    DECLARE @SQL5 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select distinct item_id, attr_val from [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] WHERE [ATTR_VAL]  LIKE ''%@VALUE%'' AND [FIELD_ID] = 413 ORDER BY [attr_val]';
    SET @SQL5 = replace(@SQL5, '@VALUE', @VALUE);
    EXEC SP_executesql @SQL5;
```

These are the results:

[image]

I am trying to take the resulting (item_id) and run another select query. Something like this:

```
UNION
Select Column3 From @SQL5 where other_column = 1234
```

The results would be 3 columns for each row returned, the 2 original and the new one found in the 2nd select.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: why are you using REPLACE if you know the value?

Comment: @McNets I don't I just have the above 123 as an example.

Comment: 'Union' requires that the two select statements return same columns (schema of the output must be the same)

Comment: What relevance does your seconds query have to the first query? From what you have explained there is no need for dynamic SQL or to do this in two steps

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The 1st query returns 'item_id'. I need to use this to get a different specific row column that has the same 'item_id' but different value in another column.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding a 'UNION' to the dynamic query it works as expected.

Comment: Does the 1234 in the second query relate to the item_id in the first query? That's what a join does. Since you have three rows in the first query, I guess you are expecting possibly three or more rows as a result from your second query? It seems that you just need use a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer without dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(100)

SET @VALUE = '123'

SELECT myuser.item_id,
       myuser.attr_val,
       parent.attr_val
FROM [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] AS myuser
JOIN [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] AS parent 
  ON parent.item_id = myuser.item_id 
  AND myuser.item_id = parent.item_id 
WHERE myuser.field_id = 239 
and parent.[ATTR_VAL]  LIKE '%' + @VALUE + '%'
```

I also moved join conditions wholly into the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
SELECT myuser.item_id,
       myuser.attr_val,
       parent.attr_val
FROM [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] AS myuser
JOIN [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] AS parent 
  ON parent.item_id = myuser.item_id 
WHERE myuser.item_id = parent.item_id and myuser.field_id = 239 and parent.[ATTR_VAL]  LIKE '%123%'
```

integrating dynamic sql:

```
    DECLARE @SQL5 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT myuser.item_id, myuser.attr_val, parent.attr_val FROM [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] AS myuser JOIN [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] AS parent ON parent.item_id = myuser.item_id WHERE myuser.item_id = parent.item_id and myuser.field_id = 239 and parent.[ATTR_VAL]  LIKE ''%@VALUE%''';
    SET @SQL5 = replace(@SQL5, '@VALUE', @VALUE);
    EXEC SP_executesql @SQL5;
```

Comment: What is the point of dynamic SQL here? You can just use a variable directly.